# PHP replace text between two strings in a string

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm trying to replace a string that comes between `284^A0N,30,24^FD` and `^FS ^FO22,314`

Example: `^FO22,284^FT22,284^A0N,30,24^FDADRIAN ROY BAGUIO^FS ^FO22,314^FT22`

In the above string i want to replace ADRIAN ROY BAGUIO with another name.

I tried the below but no luck.

```
$search = "/(284\^A0N,30,24\^FD)(.*?)(\^FS \^FO22,314)/";    
echo preg_replace($search,$firstname,$content);
```

Am i missing anything?

Comment: Can you add all of your variables? It's easier to say what you're doing wrong that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, but not sure if it is the best, but it does the job.

```
//Replacing First & Last Name
$firstRep = FindReplace($content,"284^A0N,30,24^FD", "FO22,314", $firstname." ".$lastname);

function FindReplace($content,$tagOne,$tagTwo,$reppar)
{
    $startTagPos = strrpos($content, $tagOne);
    $endTagPos = strrpos($content, $tagTwo);
    $tagLength = $endTagPos - $startTagPos + 1;
    $text = substr_replace($content, $tagOne.$reppar.'^FS ^'.$tagTwo, $startTagPos, $tagLength);    
    return $text;
}
```